# How to transform a list of dataframes into one single zoo object R

Tags: r, list, dplyr, zoo

I have a list of dataframes that I would like to convert to one single zoo object.

Example of the list:

```
> example
$A.N
# A tibble: 374 x 21
   TIMESTAMP            OPEN  HIGH   LOW CLOSE daily_return intraday_return RIC  
   <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>           <dbl> <chr>
 1 2004-04-27 00:00:00  19.6  19.9  19.3  19.4            0        -0.00997 A.N  
 2 2004-04-28 00:00:00  19.3  19.3  19.0  19.1            0        -0.0105  A.N  
 3 2004-04-29 00:00:00  19.0  19.1  18.4  18.7            0        -0.0124  A.N  
 4 2004-04-30 00:00:00  18.8  18.9  18.1  18.2            0        -0.0302  A.N  
 5 2004-05-03 00:00:00  18.2  18.6  18.1  18.4            0         0.00776 A.N  
 6 2004-05-04 00:00:00  18.5  18.5  17.5  18.0            0        -0.0262  A.N  
 7 2004-05-05 00:00:00  18.0  18.3  17.9  18.1            0         0.00337 A.N  
 8 2004-05-06 00:00:00  17.9  18.0  17.7  17.7            0        -0.00977 A.N  
 9 2004-05-07 00:00:00  17.7  18.0  17.6  17.7            0         0.00420 A.N  
10 2004-05-10 00:00:00  17.4  17.5  16.9  17.1            0        -0.0170  A.N  
# ... with 364 more rows, and 13 more variables: Acquirer Ultimate Parent (At Deal) <lgl>,
#   Acquirer Ultimate Parent Country <lgl>, Acquirer Ultimate Parent Stock Exchange <lgl>,
#   Acquirer Ultimate Parent Ticker <lgl>, Acquirer FactSet ID <chr>, Acquirer <chr>,
#   Acquirer Ownership Type <chr>, Acquirer Country <chr>, Acquirer Stock Exchange <chr>,
#   Acquirer Ticker <chr>, Announcement Date <date>, Start_Event_Study <date>,
#   End_Event_Study <date>

$ABI.BR
# A tibble: 375 x 21
   TIMESTAMP            OPEN  HIGH   LOW CLOSE daily_return intraday_return RIC   
   <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>           <dbl> <chr> 
 1 2002-11-04 00:00:00  14.0  14.3  13.2  13.3            0       -0.0473   ABI.BR
 2 2002-11-05 00:00:00  13.4  13.4  12.9  13.2            0       -0.0158   ABI.BR
 3 2002-11-06 00:00:00  13.7  14.0  13.5  14.0            0        0.0256   ABI.BR
 4 2002-11-07 00:00:00  14.0  14.4  13.7  13.7            0       -0.0192   ABI.BR
 5 2002-11-08 00:00:00  13.9  13.9  13.3  13.4            0       -0.0311   ABI.BR
 6 2002-11-11 00:00:00  13.4  14.0  13.4  13.9            0        0.0393   ABI.BR
 7 2002-11-12 00:00:00  13.8  14.3  13.7  14.1            0        0.0181   ABI.BR
 8 2002-11-13 00:00:00  13.8  13.9  13.5  13.7            0       -0.00950  ABI.BR
 9 2002-11-14 00:00:00  13.7  13.9  13.3  13.4            0       -0.0228   ABI.BR
10 2002-11-15 00:00:00  13.6  13.7  13.4  13.6            0       -0.000459 ABI.BR
# ... with 365 more rows, and 13 more variables: Acquirer Ultimate Parent (At Deal) <lgl>,
#   Acquirer Ultimate Parent Country <lgl>, Acquirer Ultimate Parent Stock Exchange <lgl>,
#   Acquirer Ultimate Parent Ticker <lgl>, Acquirer FactSet ID <chr>, Acquirer <chr>,
#   Acquirer Ownership Type <chr>, Acquirer Country <chr>, Acquirer Stock Exchange <chr>,
#   Acquirer Ticker <chr>, Announcement Date <date>, Start_Event_Study <date>,
#   End_Event_Study <date>
```

So, what I need to extract is just TIMESTAMP and INTRADAY_RETURN. I can do that with a loop. For further calculation I need one single big zoo object that should look something like this:

```
head(StockPriceReturns,3) # Time series of dates and returns.
Bajaj.Auto BHEL Bharti.Airtel Cipla Coal.India Dr.Reddy
2010-07-01 0.5277396 -1.236944 0.51151007 -0.7578608 NA -0.8436534
2010-07-02 -1.7309383 -1.669938 0.09443763 0.4910359 NA -0.3687345
2010-07-05 -0.2530097 -1.282136 0.80850304 0.1335015 NA 1.7035363
```

(this example is from eventstudies package)

The TIMESTAMPS and number of rows etc. varies in my list of dataframes.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input list shown reproducibly in the Note at the end rbind the components together to form one long data frame and then extract out the desired columns and convert to zoo using `read.zoo`.

The `aggregate=` argument to `read.zoo` provides a function which is used to aggregate values with the same date time so that there is only one of each date time within ticker.  Common values for the aggregate argument are `aggregate=mean` or `aggregate=function(x) tail(x, 1)`.  We show the first one below.  In the case of the data in the Note the datetimes are unique within ticker so the aggregate argument could optionally be omitted although if it is left in it won't hurt.

```
library(zoo)

DF <- do.call("rbind", L)[c("TIMESTAMP", "RIC", "intraday_return")]
z <- read.zoo(DF, split = "RIC", aggregate = mean); z
```

giving:

```
                A.N    ABI.BR
2002-11-04       NA -0.047300
2002-11-05       NA -0.015800
2002-11-06       NA  0.025600
2002-11-07       NA -0.019200
2002-11-08       NA -0.031100
2002-11-11       NA  0.039300
2002-11-12       NA  0.018100
2002-11-13       NA -0.009500
2002-11-14       NA -0.022800
2002-11-15       NA -0.000459
2004-04-27 -0.00997        NA
2004-04-28 -0.01050        NA
2004-04-29 -0.01240        NA
2004-04-30 -0.03020        NA
2004-05-03  0.00776        NA
2004-05-04 -0.02620        NA
2004-05-05  0.00337        NA
2004-05-06 -0.00977        NA
2004-05-07  0.00420        NA
2004-05-10 -0.01700        NA
```

## Note

We assume this input list shown in reproducible form.

```
L <- list(A.N = structure(list(TIMESTAMP = structure(c(1083038400, 
1083124800, 1083211200, 1083297600, 1083556800, 1083643200, 1083729600, 
1083816000, 1083902400, 1084161600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), OPEN = c(19.6, 19.3, 19, 18.8, 18.2, 18.5, 18, 
17.9, 17.7, 17.4), HIGH = c(19.9, 19.3, 19.1, 18.9, 18.6, 18.5, 
18.3, 18, 18, 17.5), LOW = c(19.3, 19, 18.4, 18.1, 18.1, 17.5, 
17.9, 17.7, 17.6, 16.9), CLOSE = c(19.4, 19.1, 18.7, 18.2, 18.4, 
18, 18.1, 17.7, 17.7, 17.1), daily_return = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), intraday_return = c(-0.00997, -0.0105, 
-0.0124, -0.0302, 0.00776, -0.0262, 0.00337, -0.00977, 0.0042, 
-0.017), RIC = c("A.N", "A.N", "A.N", "A.N", "A.N", "A.N", "A.N", 
"A.N", "A.N", "A.N")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame"), 
    ABI.N = structure(list(TIMESTAMP = structure(c(1036386000, 
    1036472400, 1036558800, 1036645200, 1036731600, 1036990800, 
    1037077200, 1037163600, 1037250000, 1037336400), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), OPEN = c(14, 13.4, 13.7, 14, 13.9, 
    13.4, 13.8, 13.8, 13.7, 13.6), HIGH = c(14.3, 13.4, 14, 14.4, 
    13.9, 14, 14.3, 13.9, 13.9, 13.7), LOW = c(13.2, 12.9, 13.5, 
    13.7, 13.3, 13.4, 13.7, 13.5, 13.3, 13.4), CLOSE = c(13.3, 
    13.2, 14, 13.7, 13.4, 13.9, 14.1, 13.7, 13.4, 13.6), daily_return = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), intraday_return = c(-0.0473, 
    -0.0158, 0.0256, -0.0192, -0.0311, 0.0393, 0.0181, -0.0095, 
    -0.0228, -0.000459), RIC = c("ABI.BR", "ABI.BR", "ABI.BR", 
    "ABI.BR", "ABI.BR", "ABI.BR", "ABI.BR", "ABI.BR", "ABI.BR", 
    "ABI.BR")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Somehow I get this kind of error: in merge.zoo(`000007.SZ` = c(0.0181983621474068, -0.00446428571428576,  : 
  series cannot be merged with non-unique index entries in a series

Comment: - made it work by giving it a unique() before that

Comment: Can you elaborate your example, I dont understand it. So i need each ticker to be unique? somehow unique() didnt do the job

Comment: Add `aggregate=` as an argument to `read.zoo` as shown in the updated answer.